# CodeMirror navigator not defined in Angular5

Tags: angular, codemirror, navigator

When I run my **angular5** app it builds fine.
But when I run `node dist/server.js` I am getting the following error.

```
angular\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:18
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
            ^

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at C:\Users\Lenovoz510\angular\kp\kpro-angular\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:18:17
    at userAgent (C:\Users\Lenovoz510\angular\kp\kpro-angular\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:11:82)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovoz510\angular\kp\kpro-angular\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:14:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Can someone help me with a solution?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include your code or a minimalistic and reprodocable example of your code. Otherwise you will have a tough time finding answers here. For reference check this site's [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok.Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Read the reference manuals and edit your question accordingly and you might get lucky! But tbh since you didn't adjust your question in the first hours, you likely will have to wait even longer to receive answers even if you edit it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am facing a similar issue and I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430941/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you have installed [**CodeMirror**](https://codemirror.net). It is a JavaScript Library, which is designed for use in the browser and doesn't work in Node.js.

Fortunately, there is a Node.js compatible format of it, **codemirror-node**. See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codemirror-node),

**Installation:**

`npm i codemirror-node`

**Usage:**

```
var codemirror = require('codemirror');
var code = 'alert(1);';
var lang = 'javascript';

codemirror(code, lang);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am facing a similar issue and I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430941/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some resolution.